# PyInstaller ImportError: cannot import name 'Document' from 'docx'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-docx

I'm trying to use PyInstaller to convert my script into an .exe file... My script is using the `docx` module which causes some problems trying to creating the exe. I have tried adding `docx.py` to the same directory as my script and then use PyInstaller but it still won't work: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Document' from 'docx'`. (the line that causes this error is `from docx import Document`).

Comment: Have you tested if `from docx import Document` works? it may not be because of Pyinstaller.

Comment: My script is running in IPython so I'm pretty sure it's alright

Answer (score 0):

This error is what happens if you have a module named `docx` in the same directory as your script. Instead of loading the installed `docx` module it loads the "local" one, which takes precedence.

So you need to undo that step and try something else.